# Python: Change variable in function from a child/nested function?

Tags: python, function, namespaces, global-variables

I have a function nested inside an other function. I want to change a variable inside the first function from the nested one.

```
def myfunc():
    step=0

    def increment():
        step+=1

    increment()
    increment()
    increment()
    print("Steps so far:", step)

myfunc()
```

Gives

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'step' referenced before assignment

If I try and use `global`, it won't work either since it tries to dereference to a variable `step` outside `myfunc` which doesn't exist.

Is there a way to do this without having a global variable?

Answer (score 6):

Declare `step` as a [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) variable. It will make the identifier refer the variable in enclosing scope.

```
def increment():
    nonlocal step
    step += 1
```

**NOTE** Python 3.x only.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, You're right. I added a note in the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! First time stumbling across nonlocal and it's working perfectly 